# Spring Boot Security - Multiple configurations

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot

I'm working (and struggling a little bit) on an example using spring-boot with spring security. 
My system is using a web app and also provide an REST-API, so i would like to have form based security (web) and basic auth (resp api).

As the spring documentation recommend (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity), I need to create a multi http web security configuration.

The main code works, but if I use Postman for the test of my RestApi following use-case does not work.

- All GET-requests to /restapi/ working without authentication (statuscode 200)
- All POST-requests to /restapi/ without the BASIC Auth Header are working (statuscode 401)
- All POST-requests to /restapi/ with a correct BASIC Auth Header are work (statuscode 200)
- **BUT** all requests with a wrong BASIC Auth header (f.e. user1/1234567) are returning the HTML-Loginpage defined in the first WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (FormWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)

Does anyone has an idea - what is wrong with my configuration?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private static RestAuthenticationAccessDeniedHandler restAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}12345678").roles("ADMIN").and()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}12345678").roles("USER");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http
                   .antMatcher("/restapi/**")
                   .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/restapi/**").permitAll()
                   .and()
                   .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                   .and()
                   .httpBasic()
                   .and()
                   .csrf().disable()
                   .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(UNAUTHORIZED))
                   .and()
                   .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(restAccessDeniedHandler) ;
        }
    }

    /*
        Ensures that any request to our application requires the user to be authenticated (execpt home page)
        Requests matched against "/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/index.html", "/" are fully accessible
        Allows users to authenticate with  HTTP Form Based authentication
        Configure logout with redirect to homepage
     */
    @Configuration
    public static class FormWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/index.html", "/").permitAll()
                    .and()
                        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                        .formLogin()
                            .loginPage("/login")
                            .permitAll()
                    .and()
                        .logout()
                            .logoutUrl("/logout")
                            .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                            .permitAll();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using Spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a question from some time ago but I still want to share the answer for people who are struggling with this issue. 
After a lot of searching I found out that the /error endpoint in spring boot 2.x is now secured by default. What I mean to say is in the past the /error was a endpoint what had no security at all (or didn't exist). The solution to this issue is quite straight forward.

```
antMatchers('/error').permitAll()
```

within your web security adapter configuration(s).

What happens if you don't do this, the security will check the endpoint against your configuration and if it cannot find this endpoint (/error) it will redirect to the standard login form, hence the 302.